# prop.test row wise on a large data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame of around 1000 rows and 2 columns. I would like to perform prop.test(k, n)
where k == Column1 of my data.frame and n == Column2 of my data.frame.

For example:

> ```
>  Column1(k)   Column2(n)      
>      60         500    
>      50         500     
>      70         500    
>      40         500
> ```

I would like to perform prop.test (k, n) for each row. For ex:

> ```
> prop.test(60, 500)
> prop.test(50, 500)
> prop.test(70, 500)
> ```

and so on. Since I have around 1000 rows I obviously cannot perform prop.test by hand row per row. 
How can I write a function that takes as input each row each time and perform prop.test?

Thanks  a lot,

E.

Comment: In general, always try to see if a function is vectorized and how by handing it some short sample vectors and seeing what happens.

Comment: There might  be a component of the list returned by prop.test that would be of interest but not require the long list returned by default.

Comment: There's a good answer available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279672/3124533).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` which is a wrapper for `mapply`:

```
dfr <- data.frame(k=c(60,50,70,40),n=rep(500,4))
Map(prop.test,x=dfr$k,n=dfr$n)
[[1]]

        1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  dots[[1L]][[1L]] out of dots[[2L]][[1L]], null probability 0.5 
X-squared = 287.282, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.09348364 0.15251247 
sample estimates:
   p 
0.12 


[[2]]

        1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  dots[[1L]][[2L]] out of dots[[2L]][[2L]], null probability 0.5 
X-squared = 318.402, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.07580034 0.13052865 
sample estimates:
  p 
0.1 

...
```

Note that `prop.test` has trouble with the data deparsing so it can be difficult to identify which is which.

Answer (score 1):

`prop.test` is vectorized. You can do this :

```
   prop.test(col1, col2)
```

For example :

```
dat <- data.frame(Column1 =c( 83, 90, 129, 70 ),Column2= c( 86, 93, 136, 82 ))
> prop.test(dat$Column1,dat$Column2)

    4-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  dat$Column1 out of dat$Column2
X-squared = 12.6004, df = 3, p-value = 0.005585
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
0.9651163 0.9677419 0.9485294 0.8536585
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP was asking.  This is a 4-sample test.  The OP wants 3 separate 1-sample tests.