# How to apply a function to a table to output P-values as a new row

Tags: r, function, dataframe, statistics

I have this simple dataframe. The sum column represents the sum of the row. I would like to use prop.test to determine the P-value for each column, and present that data as an additional row labeled p-value. I can use prop.test in the following way to determine a p value for any individual column, but cannot work out how to apply that to multiple columns with a single function.

```
        Other Island N_Shelf N_Shore S_Shore  Sum
Type1    10      4       1       0       3    18
Type2    19     45       1       9      11    85
```

This will output a p-value for the island column

```
ResI2<- prop.test(x=TableAvE_Island$Island, n=TableAvE_Island$Sum)
```

output:

```
data:  TableAvE_Island$Island out of TableAvE_Island$Sum
X-squared = 4.456, df = 1, p-value = 0.03478
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.56027107 -0.05410802
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.2222222 0.5294118
```

I've tried to use the apply command but cannot work out its usage, and the examples i've been able to find dont seem similar enough. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the `broom` package. It's well documented and lets you format output of tests and other operations into neat data frames

Answer (score 2):

Here's a look with `broom`'s function `tidy`, which takes output from tests and other operations and formats them as "tidy" data frames.

For the first `prop.test` that you posted, the `tidy` output looks like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

broom::tidy(prop.test(TableAvE_Island$Island, TableAvE_Island$Sum))
#>   estimate1 estimate2 statistic    p.value parameter   conf.low
#> 1 0.2222222 0.5294118  4.456017 0.03477849         1 -0.5602711
#>     conf.high
#> 1 -0.05410802
#>                                                                 method
#> 1 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
#>   alternative
#> 1   two.sided
```

To do this for all the variables in your data frame vs Sum, I `gather`ed it into a long shape

```r
table_long <- gather(TableAvE_Island, key = variable, value = val, -Sum)
head(table_long)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>     Sum variable   val
#>   <int> <chr>    <int>
#> 1    18 Other       10
#> 2    85 Other       19
#> 3    18 Island       4
#> 4    85 Island      45
#> 5    18 N_Shelf      1
#> 6    85 N_Shelf      1
```

Then grouped the long-shaped data by variable, pipe it into `do`, which allows you to call a function on each of the groups in a data frame, using `.` as a standing for the subset of the data. Then I called `tidy` on the column containing the nested results of the `prop.test`. This gives you a data frame of all the relevant results of the test, with each of "Island", "N_Shelf", etc shown.

```r
table_long %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    do(test = prop.test(x = .$val, n = .$Sum)) %>%
    broom::tidy(test)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#> # Groups:   variable [5]
#>   variable estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low
#>   <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 Island      0.222     0.529    4.46     0.0348         1  -0.560 
#> 2 N_Shelf     0.0556    0.0118   0.0801   0.777          1  -0.0981
#> 3 N_Shore     0         0.106    0.972    0.324          1  -0.205 
#> 4 Other       0.556     0.224    6.54     0.0106         1   0.0523
#> 5 S_Shore     0.167     0.129    0.00163  0.968          1  -0.183 
#> # ... with 3 more variables: conf.high <dbl>, method <fct>,
#> #   alternative <fct>
```

Created on 2018-05-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

We could `gather` into 'long' format and then store it as a `list` column

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- gather(TableAvE_Island, key, val, -Sum) %>% 
         group_by(key) %>%
         nest() %>% 
         mutate(out = map(data, ~prop.test(.x$val, .x$Sum)))
res$out
```

Comment: That introduces a number of new concepts to me, and works for what I was hoping for. Thanks.